# How do I animate a morph without using step?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I want to animate a dice being rolled, but don't want to use the `Morph>>step` methods because I want more control over when the roll finishes. I know that I can use `Delay>>wait` within a forked block to see my animation, but then how should I call this method from other methods to ensure I get the final `numberRolled`?

Here's my `roll` method:

```
roll
    | n t |
    numberRolled := nil.
    [
        t := 10 + (10 atRandom).
        t timesRepeat: [
            n := 6 atRandom.
            self showNumber: n.
            (Delay forSeconds: 0.1) wait.
        ].
        numberRolled := n.
    ] fork.
```

So if I call this from a method like `guessLower` the `roll` method returns instantly because the real work is completed in the forked process.

```
guessLower
    previousNumberRolled := numberRolled.
    self roll.
    "this next line is called before the dice has finished rolling"
    self checkWin: (numberRolled < previousNumberRolled)
```

My current solution is to modify `roll` method to take a block, which that executes after the rolling has finished e.g. `rollAndThen: aBlock` but is there a more elegant / simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Morphic it is a Really Bad Idea to use Delays and explicit looping.

But it is really simple to make the step method do what you want: Inside you simply check if it should continue rolling or not. Then you do `self stopStepping. self checkWin: ...`.

Comment: Thanks :) So I've refactored, used stepping, and my Dice is now a subclass of RectangleMorph with a method: 
`rollAndThen: aBlock
 "Roll the dice, then run aBlock (e.g. to test the numberRolled)."
 numberSteps := self randomRolls.
 finishedSteppingBlock := aBlock.
 self startStepping.`